# Remove action in a parent theme from the child theme

Tags: hooks, actions, child-theme

My question is how do I remove the action hook in the parent from the child theme?
Code from my parent theme:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wm_menu_social' ) ) {
    function wm_menu_social() {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/menu', 'social' );
        // if i place a comment here, social links won't display    
    }
} 
    add_action( 'tha_header_top', 'wm_menu_social', 130 );
```

I tried adding each of these 3 possible add_action() individually from my child theme but didn't work:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wm_remove_menu_social', 0);
//add_action( 'init', 'wm_remove_menu_social');
//add_action( 'wp_head', 'wm_remove_menu_social');

function wm_remove_menu_social() { 
   remove_action( 'tha_header_top', 'wm_menu_social' );
   echo "TESTER"; // this prints but remove action doesnt work.
}
```

As shown above, I tried to add a comment to the parent & it worked. But, we all know that the parent theme should not be touched for future updates.
I've searched this problem but nothing seemed to work.  Sorry guys, I'm still a bit new to the Wordpress API. I have created very few basic WP plugins.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority argument of `add_action` and `remove_action` need to be the same. Since `wm_menu_social` is hooked at `130` you need to specify `130` when removing it:

```
remove_action( 'tha_header_top', 'wm_menu_social', 130 );
```